# Creating a bitmap object from tiff image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bitmap, tiff, system.drawing

I have a page with a gallery where users upload images. I noticed that there is one particular user who uploaded 3 tiff images and that they cannot be accessed.

```
Exception type: System.ArgumentException
Exception message: Parameter is not valid.
```

It happens here:

```
using (Image photo = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(photoData)))
```

Files seems to be ok, sice File.ReadAllBytes() works, I can download them using other method (the one not working is used for returning a resized image only), test locally and the exception is not thrown. Any ideas what could be the case? Unfortunatelly I dont know yet if this occurs for all tiff images uploaded by other users too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for TIFF flavors (and there are many of them) depends on the version of Windows on your server. More precisely, it depends on GDI+ library's version.

Without seeing the TIFFs there is nothing more I can tell. But I can recommend you to try some 3rd party libraries just for TIFF files. There is de-facto standard [libtiff](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/) library and I have [ported it to C#](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) some time ago. You might try the port.

There are some samples you might be interested in. I think [Convert color TIFF to a 32-bit System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Samples/TiffTo32BitBitmap) might be most eligible for your task.

Comment: i use [this](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/convert-color-tiff-to-a-32-bit-system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) method exclusively for tiff images and it seems to be working (production runs on windows server 2k8, my working station on win7 so probably the problem was with that), thanks a lot!